# Angular JS dynamic directive template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, recursion

I recently came across this code when trying to create a recursive tree view in angular js:

```
testApp.directive('collection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {collection: '='},
        template: '<ul><member x-ng-repeat="member in collection" x-member="member"></member></ul>'
    };
});

testApp.directive('member', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {member: '='},
        template: '<li>{{member.title}}</li>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.children)) {
                $compile('<collection x-collection="member.children"></collection>')(scope, function (cloned, scope) {
                    element.append(cloned);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The directive is used in the HTML like so:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <collection collection="testList"></collection>
</div>
```

Where testList is an array of JSON objects in TestCtrl, for example:

```
$scope.testList = [
    {text: 'list item 1'},
    {text: 'list item 2', children: [
        {text: 'sub list item 1'},
        {text: 'sub list item 2'}
    ]},
    {text: 'list item 3'}
];
```

This code works well, but the templates for the collection directive and the member directive are hard coded. I was wondering if there is a way to get the templates for collection and member from the html. Something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <ul recurse="testList">
        <li>{{member.text}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The recurse directive would be a replacement for the collection directive but the template for recurse would the the `<ul>` element it is attached to.

Likewise, the member directive's template would be created from the children of the `<ul>` element; the `<li>` element in this case.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your directive you can use `transclude: true` and define parts of your template in HTML. The directive template can include it using `ng-transclude`.

Imagine this template:

```
<div my-list="testList">
  <b>{{item.text}}</b>
</div>
```

In your directive you can use transclusion to control how your list items gets rendered:

```
module.directive('myList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          collection: '=myList'
        },
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in collection"><div ng-transclude></div><ul><li ng-repeat="item in item.children"><div ng-transclude></li></ul></li></ul>'
    };
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zk8zOw1rvuj9AjMuJM9L?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is useful but not completely what I am looking for. For starters, the array I provided may be many levels deep in practice; an item can have child items, and they can have child items etc. This is why I need recursion. Additionally, I am trying to define the template for the directives in the html so that I can use a the directive in a number of places but change the way it is rendered (or compiled) depending on which elements I am using it on.