# ng-click firing multiple times inside ul li

Tags: angularjs

```
<ul>
  <li ng-click="setSelectedItem(member.id)">test
    <ul>
      <li ng-click="setSelectedItem(member.id)">test 2
        <ul>
          <li ng-click="setSelectedItem(member.id)">inner test2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above tree structure is generated by two directives by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580273/angular-js-dynamic-directive-template) stack overflow question.

When **test** is clicked **setSelectedItem()** gets called once. When **test2** is clicked **setSelectedItem()** gets called twice. When **inner test2** is clicked **setSelectedItem()** gets called thrice.

Can anyone help me solve this. I want the click to be called only once when clicking the inner li tags. Thanks

Comment: try add `e.stopPropagation()` to stop event from bubbling up

Comment: U can attach ng-click directive to the parent ul and access the targets using event.target property

Comment: Show your code for setSelectedItem function.

Comment: why you need three same click handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop event propogation, use below code.

```
  <li ng-click="setSelectedItem(member.id); $event.stopPropagation();">test</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$event.stopPropagation();`. To prevent bubling of click event to the parents.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-click="setSelectedItem(member.id);$event.stopPropagation();">test
    <ul>
      <li ng-click="setSelectedItem(member.id);$event.stopPropagation();">test 2
        <ul>
          <li ng-click="setSelectedItem(member.id);$event.stopPropagation();">inner test2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: on first level not necessary

Comment: @Grundy Just added as a precaution, because we are not sure what is the parent element and its bindings.